# How to set the color of an Eclipse/RCP decorator?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I added a decorator in a Eclipse/RCP application to my tree viewer items by *plugin.xml*:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators">
      <decorator
            adaptable="true"
            class="sernet.verinice.samt.rcp.TopicDecorator"
            id="sernet.verinice.samt.rcp.TopicDecorator"
            label="ISA Topic decorator"
            lightweight="true"
            location="BOTTOM_LEFT"
            state="true">
         <enablement>
            <objectClass name="sernet.verinice.model.samt.SamtTopic"/>        
         </enablement>
      </decorator>
```

In the decorator class i set the decoration suffix which works fine:

```
public class TopicDecorator extends LabelProvider implements ILightweightLabelDecorator, {
  ControlMaturityService maturityService = new ControlMaturityService();    
  @Override
  public void decorate(Object element, IDecoration decoration) {
     decoration.addSuffix( new StringBuilder().append(" [")
       .append(maturityService.getWeightedMaturity((IControl)element))
       .append("]").toString() );   
     decoration.setForegroundColor(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 150,90,90));     
   }
```

As you can see i also tried to set the foreground color of the suffic which has no effect. Suffix has the same color as the label in the tree: black.

How can i set the color of the decoration suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just had success getting a different coloured text decoration using a wrapper class `TreeElementDecoratingLabelProvider` for  `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingLabelProvider`:

```
public class TreeElementDecoratingLabelProvider extends DecoratingLabelProvider {
   public TreeElementDecoratingLabelProvider(ILabelProvider provider,   ILabelDecorator decorator) {
      super(provider, decorator);
   }

    @Override
    public Color getForeground(Object element) {
      //return your color for element...
      return Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just had success getting a different coloured text decoration using a [org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FDecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.html) that wrapps an `IStyledLabelProvider`, and an `ILabelDecorator`.

I think the key is the `getStyledText` method of the `LabelProvider`, that allows custom styling of the text

Comment: Just wanted to add that the `DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider` can be used to wrap a `IStyledLabelProvider` in cases where one does not want a decorator, but rather just a label provider which creates styled labels directly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should try to change the order - set setForegroundColor() first and then add a suffix.

Hint: to not initialize any colour by yourself, you may use Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN); Then you need to care about disposing of this colour - it's freed by the system.

Comment: It makes no difference whether you call setForegroundColor(..) first or after addSuffix(..). Suffix has still the same color as the rest of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator needs to implement org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IColorDecorator if it needs to provide various colors

Comment: My TopicDecorator now also implements IColorDecorator. Implemented methods decorateBackground and decorateForeground both returns  statically one different color but decorator string ist still black with white backround.

Comment: Make sure "Use Mixed fonts and colors" preference is checked (Prefereces->General->Apperance) and disable all other decorators (General->Appearance->Label decorators) and see whether it works

Answer (score 1):

You just have to implement `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IColorProvider` in your `LabelProvider`

```
public class MyLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements IColorProvider {

    public String getText(Object element){
        return String.valueOf(element)
    }

    public Color getForeground(Object element){
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        return display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY);
    }

    public Color getBackground(Object element){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a `DecoratingLabelProvider`. Usually you use the workbench's decorator, because it detects the decorator registered by the extension-point `org.eclipse.ui.decorators`. See [The Java Developer's Guide to Eclipse](https://books.google.de/books?id=6Ob1ANNVcXcC&lpg=PA399&ots=joIr5LOhyx&dq=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager()%3B&hl=de&pg=PA399#v=onepage&q=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager();&f=false).

```
ILabelProvider baseLabelProvider = new MyLabelProvider();
IDecoratorManager decoratorManager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager();
ILabelDecorator decorator = decoratorManager.getLabelDecorator();
DecoratingLabelProvider decoratingLabelProvider = new DecoratingLabelProvider(baseLabelProvider, decorator);
```

and use it as normal

```
TableViewer viewer = ...;
viewer.setLabelProvider(decoratingLabelProvider);
```

The `DecoratingLabelProvider` automatically detects if the `LabelProvider` it uses is an

- [IFontProvider](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FIFontProvider.html)
- [IColorProvider](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FIColorProvider.html)

**For more sophisticated decorations** take a look at [`WorkbenchLabelProvider`](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fmodel%2FWorkbenchLabelProvider.html).

I often use the `WorkbenchLabelProvider` in combination with the `DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider`, because they perfectly integrate with the workbench.

I see two benefits with this approach:

1. [`WorkbenchAdapter`](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fmodel%2FWorkbenchAdapter.html) is easier to use than the `LableProvider`s
2. `WorkbenchLabelProvider` manages the system resources like `Color`s for you. 
   So don't forget to dispose the `WorkbenchLabelProvider`.

Here is a code snippet that I often use:

```
ILabelDecorator labelDecorator = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager().getLabelDecorator();
DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider labelProvider = new DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider(
            new WorkbenchLabelProvider(), labelDecorator, null);
tableViewer.setLabelProvider(labelProvider);
tableViewer.getTable().addDisposeListener((e) -> labelProvider.dispose());
```